# Linux pass execution directly to Grub on reboot

Tags: linux, bootsector

Is it possible to have Linux, upon reboot, pass execution to Grub without actually rebooting and invoking the BIOS? I have a GPT hard disk that I nee dplugged it at startup but the BIOS refuses to pass POST with it. I have looked at Coreboot but my MCP61 motherboard is onfortunately not supported.

Comment: It is certainly possible, assuming *you* are capable of hacking the kernel.  Nobody else wants this "feature".  Most system software assumes that the HW has been quiesced by a reset signal, but you want to skip that reset.  Hard to tell what may break if the SW is not capable of a boot w/o reset.

Comment: @sawdust OK, case closed.